# Find Average color from image By Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have image By division `imgProcess.ROI = rectangle[i]` but I can't not Find Average color from image

I think Emgu CV may be function for Find Average color.

[image]!

Comment: Fine Average color Each rectangle

Answer (score 2):

There is `Image.GetAverage()` method available which will do the job. There also an overload of `Image.GetAverage(mask)`, which will take a mask if you need a non-rectangular region: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.4.0.0/html/3b71b52b-48a1-a3de-d3f6-75010ef3ff26.htm

(from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049573)

Answer (score 1):

EmguCV has wrapper function of openCV function `AvgSdv()`,
it depends on which version you are using, if you have image like

```
Image<byte,rgb> img
```

image object have implementation of CV function, one of them will be `img.AvgSdv()` 
reference
[here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/24dc084c-0935-08c9-213f-d677e7dc8e78.htm)
you can use `CvInvoke.MeanStdDev()`
reference
[here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/a3b57d14-ae7b-4b2f-eae2-89d38ec71ff9.htm)

if you want to get average color of any ROI(region of intrest) then you can segment that region and apply these methods on them as well